# Angular unit test if component method is called according to a data from a service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I can't figure out how to test if a component method is fired or not on service data condition...

service looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

    someData() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

comp:

```
export class SomeComponent {

    constructor(private someService: SomeService) { 

        if (this.someService.someData()) {
            this.someMethod();
        } else {
            console.log('keep kalm!');
        }
    }

    someMethod() {
        console.log('some method is fired!')
    }
}
```

test:

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
    let component: SomeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>; 

    let mockSomeService = {
        someData: () => true
    }

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [SomeComponent],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: SomeService, useValue: mockSomeService
                }
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('method should be called', () => {
        spyOn(component, 'someMethod'); 

        expect(component.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
    });
});
```

The component someMethod fires but test fails with:

> Expected spy someMethod to have been called.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the test error saying ?

Comment: @e.m.b Expected spy someMethod to have been called.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oke It is fixed! thanks to the answer from @Supamiu

Incase someone will need it in the future:

Move the initialization into ngOnInit, remove fixture.detectChanges(); from beforeEach and execute it in the test. So:

Comp:

```
constructor(private someService: SomeService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    if (this.someService.someData()) {
        this.someMethod();
    } else {
        console.log('keep kalm!');
    }
}
```

test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // fixture.detectChanges(); <<< Remove this
});

it('method should be called', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'someMethod'); 
    fixture.detectChanges(); // trigger ngOnInit here

    expect(component.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

you are setting up the spy too late. By the time you mount the spy on service, it has already been constructed and `someMethod` has been called. So after `defining` the component call the spy

```
it('method should be called', () => {
        var spy = spyOn(component, "someMethod").and.callThrough();
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
        expect(spy);
        expect(component.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the spy *before* you create the component, because spies can't look in the past and since your method is only called in constructor, it hasn't been called after you created the spy.

You should move your initialization to either `ngOnInit` method or a simple `init()` method called in constructor, this way to can call the `init` method or `ngOnInit` and check that `someMethod`has been called.