# getting Error: Expected spy onSubmit to have been called

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular5

I am new in angular and trying to write unit testing in angular 5 using karma-jasmine.

i have a login page which has 2 parameter username and password, and onSubmit() is function which is used to call api to authenticate user. check below file for login component.

**login.component.ts**

```
@Component({

  selector: 'app-login',

  templateUrl: './login.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']

})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  myform: FormGroup;

  username: FormControl;

  password: FormControl;

  errMsg: string;

  loginErr: boolean;


  model: any = {};

  constructor(

    private http: Http,

    private router: Router

  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.createFormControls();

    this.createForm();
  }


  createFormControls() {

    this.username = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

    this.password = new FormControl('', [

      Validators.required,

      Validators.minLength(6)

    ]);

  }

  createForm() {

    this.myform = new FormGroup({

      username: this.username,

      password: this.password

    });
    enter code here

  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.errMsg = "";
    if (this.myform.valid) {

      var data = {
        'Username': this.username.value,
        'Password': this.password.value
      };

      var options = {
        type: "POST",
        url: GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL + "authentication/authenticate-user",
        content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        processing: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      };

      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

      this.http.post(options.url, options.body, { headers: headers }).subscribe((data) => {

        console.log(JSON.parse(data['_body']));

      }, (err) => {
        console.log(data['_body']);
        this.errMsg = "Invalid Login Attempt.";
      }, () => {
        console.log("All Good With The Data")
      });
    }
    else
    {

     }
  }

}
```

Now i am trying to write unit test for above file, check below spec.ts file for sample code

****login.component.spec.ts****

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {

  let component//: LoginComponent;

  let fixture//: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, AppRoutingModule, RouterModule, FormsModule],
      providers: [
        {provide: Globals, useValue: GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL},
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create login component', () => {

    spyOn(component,'onSubmit').and.callThrough();
    component.username = 'username';
    component.password = '12345678';
    expect(component.onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

when I have run this unit test it shows error as image attached, please suggest me what mistake is in my code. how I can write a unit test to authenticate user by passing username and password and call the onSubmit function.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue in one of my component's test in `Angular 6` application. What I did is, I moved my `spyOn` section before the component section. After that, my tests were running fine.

**Before**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HomeComponent, SingleNewsComponent, NewsComponent, DummyComponent],
      imports: [MatCardModule, MatSelectModule, MatButtonModule, HttpModule, NewsRouterModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
        ApiService]
    })
      .compileComponents();
    spyOn(apiService, 'post').and.returnValue(new Observable<any>());
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SingleNewsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    apiService = TestBed.get(ApiService);
  }));
```

**After**

```
.compileComponents();
apiService = TestBed.get(ApiService);
spyOn(apiService, 'post').and.returnValue(new Observable<any>());
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SingleNewsComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
```

As you can see, I have changed the order of the service spy. Thanks to Supamiu for putting some light on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48024756/5550507). Hope it helps.